# How containers are assigned in YARN?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

In Mapreduce 1, the Jobtracker get the Block information from the NameNode and then assign Task(most likely) to the Task Tracker that are available in the Same node as where the Datablocks is present. There by the performance can be increased.

How this is taken care in YARN? Is Application Manager responsible for getting block information from the NameNode?

If so, How the containers are assigned to those Application master? Did Resource Manager considers the DataBlock location while assigning the Container? or it randomly assign any container in a Node?

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking its the role of `JobClient` to compute the [input splits](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputSplit.html), this splits information is placed in HDFS from where ApplicationMaster will picks it off and uses this information while requesting the containers from ResourceManager.

So, technically, Application Master while requesting the containers for all the map tasks the information about each map task's data locality is passed along to ResourceManager. The scheduler uses this information to make scheduling decisions, attempting to assign tasks local to data.

Comment: Can I assign containers manuallay. I have 10 InputSplits and 20 nodes in my custer. Each Inputsplit will be running on one node. 10 nodes will be idle. Is there a way to use these nodes as well for the 10 InputSplits? How slots come into this picture?